# Flutter issue on publishing app on Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play

Running "flutter packages get" in NativeApplication...              2.0s
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           9.8s
ProGuard, version 6.0.3
Reading input...
....
Initializing...

**Warning: io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin: can't find referenced method 'ActivityManager$TaskDescription(java.lang.String,int,int)' in library class android.app.ActivityMana
ger$TaskDescription
Warning: io.flutter.view.ResourceExtractor: can't find referenced method 'long getLongVersionCode()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageInfo
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.**
         ([http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember](http://%20http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember**))
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Thread(Tasks limiter_2): destruction

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> Job failed, see logs for details
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 19s
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      19.7s
>
> ---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you have `minifyEnabled true` in your `build.gradle(app)`.

There are 2 solutions.

1. Remove `minifyEnabled true`
2. Follow these steps.

In your `<ProjectRoot>/android/gradle.properties`, add

```
extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate
```

You need to create the file in `/android/app/proguard-rules.pro`

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

And add to `/android/app/build.gradle` typical proguard config

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15100)

Comment: 1st method is working thanks a lot. 2nd method is not working. I added shrinkResources false. but still getting error